# TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

please help me with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/Speaker-Identification-Python-master/Speaker-Identification-Python-master/modeltraining.py", line 44, in
gmm = GMM(n_components = 16, n_iter = 200, covariance_type='diag',n_init = 3)
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter'
```

Comment: Please, share with us the code that generates this error, with example of input and the output that you want

Comment: Also, tell us the current version of scikit-learn you are using.

Comment: scikit-learn==0.22.1

Comment: Good, please go through my answer and make necessary changes in your ```modeltraining.py``` file and tell me If it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the GitHub repo https://github.com/Atul-Anand-Jha/Speaker-Identification-Python you downloaded and trying to execute the `modeltraining.py` file, which was committed 2 years ago.

The thing here is, the Author of the repo might have used an older version of **scikit-learn(v0.16)**.

In older version scikit-learn, He used **`from sklearn.mixture import GMM`**

Assuming that you have newer version of scikit-learn (version 0.18 or above).

**Use `from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture`**

Because as per the Official documentation :

**In scikit-learn(version 0.16)** - https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html

`class sklearn.mixture.GMM(n_components=1, covariance_type='diag', random_state=None, thresh=None, tol=0.001, min_covar=0.001, n_iter=100, n_init=1, params='wmc', init_params='wmc')`

`n_iter` parameter is present.

**But in scikit-learn(version 0.18 or above)** - https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html

`class sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=1, covariance_type='full', tol=0.001, reg_covar=1e-06, max_iter=100, n_init=1, init_params='kmeans', weights_init=None, means_init=None, precisions_init=None, random_state=None, warm_start=False, verbose=0, verbose_interval=10)`

There is no `n_iter` paramter but they replaced it with `max_iter`.

**So, try renaming your `n_iter` parameter to `max_iter`** and also use this **`from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture`** instead of  **`from sklearn.mixture import GMM`** .

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Speaker-Identification-Python-master/Speaker-Identification-Python-master/modeltraining.py", line 49, in <module>
    cPickle.dump(gmm, open(dest + picklefile, 'w'))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Change this ```cPickle.dump(gmm,open(dest + picklefile,'w'))``` to this ```cPickle.dump(gmm,open(dest + picklefile,'wb'))```